Different Configurations for Different Product Variants
I am encountering an issue with the configuration of product variants in Odoo.
I have a product with two variants, t-shirt with sizes L and XL. I want customers to be able to order size L even if it's out of stock, but I want to restrict orders for size XL when it's out of stock.
I noticed that there is a checkbox named "Continue selling if the product is out of stock" in the product variant configuration under the Sale tab. However, when I check this checkbox for one variant (size L), it automatically applies to the other variant (size XL) as well. This is causing unwanted behavior as I only want to apply this option to size L, not to all variants.
How to configure the product variants so that the "Continue Selling" option applies selectively to specific variants, rather than being applied universally across all variants?

The out of stock option is implemented for the product templates. So AFAIK there is no chance to configure it on variants in vanilla odoo.

Considering Odoo's limitations, I'm exploring using "Additional Product Tags" at the variant level to selectively disable the "Add to Cart" button. e.g. for variants that have tag "unavailable" the "Add to Cart" button will be disable. Could this approach effectively restrict sales for specific variants? Are there any potential challenges or drawbacks?

I'm not full aware of the shop system and what logic is used to handle variant stock knowledge. But if you consider using variant tags you could also use an out-of-stock Boolean field per variant (new field...) and use that instead. Drawbacks are in the shop, if variant attributes like available stock aren't used for any checks, because everything is build on base of product templates. But as mentioned at the beginning, i'm not that experienced with the shop system of odoo in technical behalfs.
